# How to get all weeks between two dates?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe `just_dates`:

```
0     2003-01-02
1     2015-10-31
2     2015-11-01
16    2015-11-02
33    2015-11-03
44    2015-11-04
```

and a dataframe `weeks` which I calculated with

```
df['weeks'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df.just_dates, freq='W')
```

`weeks` looks like:

```
0    2002-12-30/2003-01-05
1    2015-10-26/2015-11-01
2    2015-10-26/2015-11-01
16   2015-11-02/2015-11-08
33   2015-11-02/2015-11-08
44   2015-11-02/2015-11-08
```

Now I want to have a data frame with all the weeks between the first and the last week, so `all_weeks` should look like:

```
0  2002-12-30/2003-01-05
1  2003-01-06/2003-01-12
2  2003-01-13/2003-01-19
...
   2015-10-26/2015-11-01
   2015-10-26/2015-11-01
   2015-11-02/2015-11-08
   2015-11-02/2015-11-08
   2015-11-02/2015-11-08
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`pandas.period_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.period_range.html):

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.period_range(start=df.weeks.min(),
                             end=df.weeks.max(),
                             freq='W'))
```

[out]

```
                         0
0    2002-12-30/2003-01-05
1    2003-01-06/2003-01-12
2    2003-01-13/2003-01-19
3    2003-01-20/2003-01-26
4    2003-01-27/2003-02-02
5    2003-02-03/2003-02-09
..                     ...
665  2015-09-28/2015-10-04
666  2015-10-05/2015-10-11
667  2015-10-12/2015-10-18
668  2015-10-19/2015-10-25
669  2015-10-26/2015-11-01
670  2015-11-02/2015-11-08

[671 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: I use `all_weeks=pd.DataFrame(pd.period_range(start=df.weeks.min(), end=df.weeks.max()))` and become just the dates between 2003-01-05 and 2015-11-08. What went wrong?

Comment: what's your expected output..?

Comment: Hmmm what version of pandas are you using? I ran the above and got the output using `0.24.2` - maybe just requires upgrading: `pip install pandas -U` from a terminal

Comment: My version is ` 0.22.0`. Ok will try !

Comment: If that fails, try explicitly passing the arg `freq='W'` to the `period_range` method

Comment: with the new version it fails in `df['weeks'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df.just_dates, freq='W'). But I need both, an vector with the weeks of mediates in `just_dates` as well an vector with all weeks between..

Comment: and what is `df.just_dates.dtype` ?  -  I think you may just need to cast as `datetime` type first... `df['just_dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['just_dates'])` ?

Comment: When I use `print(df.just_dates.dtype)`  there come "object"

Comment: Yeh, you'll need to cast `just_dates` to datetime - `df['just_dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['just_dates'])`; then _hopefully_ the above should work

Comment: perfect, that works, thank you! Just for interest, why does it work with the old version?

Comment: I'm not sure, can be useful to keep an eye on the [release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/index.html#), sometimes there are just subtle changes like this made between versions