# Converting the available pandas Dataframe presently across monthly into quarterly values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

This is my available df, it contains year from 2016 to 2020

```
Year Month Bill 
-----------------
2016   1     2
2016   2     5
2016   3     10
2016   4     2
2016   5     4
2016   6     9
2016   7     7
2016   8     8
2016   9     9
2016   10    5
2016   11    1
2016   12    3
.
.
.
2020   12    10
```

Now I want to create a 2 new columns in this dataframe **Level** and **Contribution**.
and the level column contain Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 representing 4 quarters of the year and **Contribution** contains average value from bill column of each quarter in those 3 months of the respective year.

```
for example Q1 for 2016 will contains the average of month 1,2,3 of bill across **Contribution** 
and same for Q3 for year 2020 will contains average of month 7,8,9 of the year 2020 bill column in the Contribution Column, expected Dataframe is given below
```

```
Year Month  Bill  levels contribution
------------------------------------
2016   1     2     Q1      5.66
2016   2     5     Q1      5.66
2016   3     10    Q1      5.66
2016   4     2     Q2      5
2016   5     4     Q2      5
2016   6     9     Q2      5
2016   7     7     Q3      8
2016   8     8     Q3      8
2016   9     9     Q3      8
2016   10    5     Q4      3
2016   11    1     Q4      3
2016   12    3     Q4      3
.
.
2020   10    2     Q4      6 
2020   11    6     Q4      6
2020   12    10    Q4      6
```

This process will be repeated for each month 4 quarters
Iam not able to figure out the as it is something new to me

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df['levels'] = 'Q' + df['Month'].div(3).apply(math.ceil).astype(str)
df['contribution'] = df.groupby(['Year', 'levels'])['Bill'].transform('mean')
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas actually has a set of datatypes for monthly and quarterly values called [`Pandas.Period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Period.html).

See this similar question:

- [How to create a period range with year and week of year in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71329189/how-to-create-a-period-range-with-year-and-week-of-year-in-python)

In your case it would look like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

# First create dates for 1st of each month period
df['Dates'] = [datetime(row['Year'], row['Month'], 1) for i, row in df[['Year', 'Month']].iterrows()]

# Create monthly periods
df['Month Periods'] = df['Dates'].dt.to_period('M')

# Use the new monthly index
df = df.set_index('Month Periods')

# Group by quarters
df_qtrly = df['Bill'].resample('Q').mean()
df_qtrly.index.names = ['Quarters']

print(df_qtrly)
```

Result:

```
Quarters
2016Q1    5.666667
2016Q2    5.000000
2016Q3    8.000000
2016Q4    3.000000
Freq: Q-DEC, Name: Bill, dtype: float64
```

If you want to put these values back into the monthly dataframe you could do this:

```
df['Quarters'] = df['Dates'].dt.to_period('Q')
df['Contributions'] = df_qtrly.loc[df['Quarters']].values
```

```
               Year  Month  Bill      Dates Quarters  Contributions
Month Periods                                                      
2016-01        2016      1     2 2016-01-01   2016Q1       5.666667
2016-02        2016      2     5 2016-02-01   2016Q1       5.666667
2016-03        2016      3    10 2016-03-01   2016Q1       5.666667
2016-04        2016      4     2 2016-04-01   2016Q2       5.000000
2016-05        2016      5     4 2016-05-01   2016Q2       5.000000
2016-06        2016      6     9 2016-06-01   2016Q2       5.000000
2016-07        2016      7     7 2016-07-01   2016Q3       8.000000
2016-08        2016      8     8 2016-08-01   2016Q3       8.000000
2016-09        2016      9     9 2016-09-01   2016Q3       8.000000
2016-10        2016     10     5 2016-10-01   2016Q4       3.000000
2016-11        2016     11     1 2016-11-01   2016Q4       3.000000
2016-12        2016     12     3 2016-12-01   2016Q4       3.000000
```